# Why isn't this rewrite rule catching?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with a bunch of assets using absolute paths, ie:

```
<img src=\"/_files/images/shell/logo.jpg\">
```

My issue is, the url for this site in development is: http://arraybox.net/~hazelwoodconstru/

Unfortunately, this means it is trying to access the files at `arraybox.net/_files/images/shell/logo.jpg` instead of `arraybox.net/~hazelwoodconstru/_files/images/shell/logo.jpg`

I'm trying to handle this with an .htaccess RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule /_files/(.*) /~hazelwoodconstru/_files/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

I had it working at some point, but I messed around with it, and now it's broken and I can't figure out why!

**EDIT:**

I also have the following in this .htaccess which may or may not be interfering:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404\.shtml|500\.shtml|favicon\.ico|index\.php{1}
RewriteRule (.*) /~hazelwoodconstru/ [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the absolute file paths just plain old won't use `arraybox.net/~hazelwoodconstru/filepath` - they go straight to `arraybox.net/filepath`. Writing the .htaccess on the main directory arraybox.net won't work for me, because there will be multiple sites using this setup, and there is no way to tell which /home/ directory the assets really live in.

The solution I went with:

Instead of using the user directory `arraybox.net/~hazelwoodconstru`, I set up a subdomain 
`hazelwood.arraybox.net`.

I then edited the vhosts config to change the document root for this subdomain to point to the /home/hazelwoodconstru directory (I also had to change the user).

Additionally I had to modify vhosts.local to change phpopenbasedirprotect to use documentroot. Then I had to add `allow from all` on the /home/ directory.

It's now working on the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the rule's matching more strict, as well as removing the leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^_files/ /~hazelwoodconstru/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Remove the `,R` flag if you don't want an external redirect.

Comment: No beans - added some info above re: additional rules that might be interfering.

Comment: @SarahBromley you need to add this rule **before** the rule you already have, which routes *everything* wholesale to the `/~hazelwoodconstru/` directory, thus making it so anything after that rule will never be reached.

Comment: @SarahBromley dunno then, rule works perfectly fine for me in a vanilla apache with a blank htaccess file in the document root.

Comment: I had a hunch this is more than a rule typo...as it was working and then stopped. I wonder if it has something to do with the server?